# Create video thumbnail based on a video link in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, thumbnails

I am looking for a way to create video thumbnail based on a video being played from a link, previously I was using `react-native-create-thumbnail` but it not working with Android sdk 33.

This is how it should work:

```html
import { createThumbnail } from "react-native-create-thumbnail";

          if (item.fileType === "video") {
            createThumbnail({
              url: item.links![4].url,
            })
              .then((response) => {
                if (!thumbnail) {
                  setThumbnail(response.path);
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => console.warn({ err }));
          }
```

Comment: is there an error in the catch block? is there a response in the then block? what is the `thumbnail` variable in the then block? we need more info here.

Comment: Just not building after updating to Android SDK 33, they even have opened issue about this.

Comment: if it's a specific error with the package then there's probably not much that can be done until the third party package fix it or provide a workaround. In any case, there is no where near enough info here. What is the error when you try to build with SDK 33? What is the github issue you mention? Please read the minimum reproducible example guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example